# PHP DateInterval does not return 31th day of a month

Tags: php, date

Using DateInterval in PHP for 1 day period from 01 to 31 days in a month that have 31th day does not return 31 day in result.

Why this happens?

```
<?php

$days_list = array();

$days_period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2019-05-01'),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    new DateTime('2019-05-31')
);

foreach ($days_period as $key => $value) {
    $days_list[] = $value->format('D, d M');
}

foreach ($days_list as $day) {
    echo $day.'<br>';
}
```

This display days from 01 May to 30 May of 2019. Why 31 May 2019 is not here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add 1 sec to end date

```
$days_list   = [];
$days_period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2019-05-01'),
    new DateInterval('P1D'),
    (new DateTime('2019-05-31'))->modify("+1 second")
);
foreach ($days_period as $key => $value) {
    $days_list[] = $value->format('D, d M');
}
foreach ($days_list as $day) {
    echo $day . '<br>';
}
```

**EDIT**

As per your requirement, I made changes in above code, please see inline doc for explanation

```
$temp = '';
// I am considering snippet for 1 month
foreach ($days_period as $key => $value) {
    // check if empty assign temp as current month's value
    if (empty($temp)) {
        $temp = $value->format("M");
    }
    // if any changes in iterator not matched with current month then break
    if ($temp != $value->format("M")) {
        break;
    }
    $days_list[] = $value->format('D, d M');
}
foreach ($days_list as $day) {
    echo $day . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but now how to prevent 31th day from being added for a month that don't have it? For ex. if I use June 2019 I get 30 days from June AND 1 day from July.

Comment: Once check my edit portion of answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because DatePeriod does not include the last date specified.